# Concatenate 1st Column values with column headers in Pandas to get a tall and skinny format tabel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, combinations

I want to concatenate 1st column values with column headers to get a tall and skinny format table using pandas.
for example-  the input is

```
Freq    Low     High
 B1     19       22
 B2     20       23
```

the expected output I am looking for is

```
Freq      value     
B1_Low     19
B1_High    22
B2_Low     20
B2_High    23
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `melt` then concat the frequency and variable column that result.

```
df = df.melt(id_vars='Freq')
df['Freq'] = df['Freq'].str.cat(df['variable'], sep='_')
print(df[['Freq','value']])
```

Output

```
      Freq  value
0   B1_Low     19
1   B2_Low     20
2  B1_High     22
3  B2_High     23
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.stack()` and then `.get_level_values()` on index:

```
df = df.set_index('Freq').T.stack()
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':df.values}, index=(df.index.get_level_values(1) + '_' + df.index.get_level_values(0)) )
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
         value
B1_Low      19
B2_Low      20
B1_High     22
B2_High     23
```